# Sign-in CRASH in Android Game (Play Games Services)

Tags: java, android

I wanted to design an app and I need to do to log a user.

So I followed this guide :[https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init ]

**On the emulator app works, but if I copy the apk on phone when I run mGoogleApiClient.connect (); crash.**

Here My code : Suggestion ? ( I have imported Basegameutils library  as saying the guide)

**MainActivity :**

```
package com.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.games.Games;
import com.google.example.games.basegameutils.BaseGameUtils;

public class MainActivity  extends Activity implements
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
            .build();


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}


@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {

}



private static int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;

private boolean mResolvingConnectionFailure = false;
private boolean mAutoStartSignInFlow = true;
private boolean mSignInClicked = false;

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    if (mResolvingConnectionFailure) {
        // already resolving
        return;
    }

    if (mSignInClicked || mAutoStartSignInFlow) {
        mAutoStartSignInFlow = false;
        mSignInClicked = false;
        mResolvingConnectionFailure = true;

        if (!BaseGameUtils.resolveConnectionFailure(this,
                mGoogleApiClient, connectionResult,
                RC_SIGN_IN, getString(R.string.signin_other_error))) {
            mResolvingConnectionFailure = false;
        }
    }


}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        mSignInClicked = false;
        mResolvingConnectionFailure = false;
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        } else {
            BaseGameUtils.showActivityResultError(this,
                    requestCode, resultCode, R.string.signin_failure);
        }
    }
 }


}
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.myapplication">


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>



<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
            android:value="Xxxxxx"></meta-data>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.appstate.APP_ID"
            android:value="Xxxxxx" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"></meta-data>


        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Logcat :

```
01-14 13:55:23.129 25190-25190/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni     (already on)
01-14 13:55:23.130 25190-25190/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86     using defaults: x86
01-14 13:55:23.158 25190-25190/com.myapplication W/System: ClassLoader     referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.myapplication-2/lib/x86
01-14 13:55:23.177 25190-25190/com.myapplication I/InstantRun: Instant     Run Runtime started. Android package is com.myapplication, real     application class is null.

                                                               [ 01-14     13:55:23.181  1557: 1582 D/         ]
                                                                   HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x9bffcc00, tid 1582
01-14 13:55:25.351 25190-25190/com.myapplication W/System: ClassLoader     referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.myapplication-    2/lib/x86
01-14 13:55:25.454 25190-25190/com.myapplication W/art: Before Android     4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter     android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(andro    id.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList,     android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode)     would have incorrectly overridden the     package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
01-14 13:55:25.553 25190-25190/com.myapplication W/PopupManager: You     have not specified a View to use as content view for popups. Falling back to     the Activity content view. Note that this may not work as expected in     multi-screen environments
01-14 13:55:25.606 25190-25251/com.myapplication I/OpenGLRenderer:     Initialized EGL, version 1.4
01-14 13:55:25.606 25190-25251/com.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap     behavior 1
01-14 13:55:25.641 25190-25251/com.myapplication E/EGL_emulation: tid     25251: eglSurfaceAttrib(1146): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
01-14 13:55:25.641 25190-25251/com.myapplication W/OpenGLRenderer:     Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xb6a38da0, error=EGL_BAD_MATCH
```

Comment: Add Logcat please

Comment: thanks for the reply, I modified

Comment: There is no crash in that

Comment: On the emulator not, but on my phone yes, the app crash when use mGoogleApiClient.connect()

Comment: No, I'm saying we can't help if there is no exception raised that you're going to show